# Fine-grained WiFi Tx Signal Strength control on a accesspoint

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, linux-device-driver, signal-strength, wireless-access-point

I'm trying to reduce TX power on an AP in order to minimize area in which devices can connect to the AP. I've tried to do this by iwconfig command such as `iwconfig wlan0 txpower 1mw` but it didn't work well. Even though txpower was set 1mw the area didn't seem to be reduced significantly.

Is there a method to control TX power more fine-grained way? I'm using TP-LINK N300 as a softAP mode on Ubuntu 14.04.

Any leads could be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: TP-LINK N300 Wireless Mini USB Adapter (TL-WN823N) is my wireless adapter.

Comment: Thank you @shellter . Actually I also need this kind of comment because I'm not familiar with this community yet. I used flag link to ask to move my Q to more proper site.

Comment: There is also http://askubuntu.com . In reality, I would look for a more specialized forum, maybe even at TP-Link. Good luck.